# Combine vs ParDo in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

May I know the exact difference between a ParDo and a Combine transformation in Apache Beam?

Can I see ParDo as the Map phase in the map/shuffle/reduce while Combine as the reduce phase?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understand Apache Beam, there are no explicit Map and Reduce phases.

You can apply several element-wise map functions in a row, where `ParDo` is the most general class that can be used for own implementation.

The term reduce has been replaced by aggregation and there the corresponding class is `Combine`.

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce is limited to graphs of the shape Map-Shuffle-Reduce, where Reduce is an elementwise operation, just like map, that is distinguished only by following the shuffle.

In Apache Beam, one can have arbitrary topologies, e.g.

```
Map-Map-Shuffle-Map-Shuffle-Map-Map-Shuffle-Map
```

so the notion of breaking phases down by that which follows shuffle no longer holds. (Beam calls Map/Shuffle ParDo and GroupByKey respectively.)

Combine operations are a special kind of Map operations that are known to be associative (think `sum`, `max`, etc. but they can be much more complicated) which allow us to push part of the work *before* the shuffle, e.g.

```
Shuffle-Sum
```

becomes

```
PartialSum-Shuffle-Sum
```

(Most MapReduce systems also have this notion, named combining or semi-reducing or similar.)

Note that Beam's CombinePerKey and GlobalCombine operations pair the shuffle with the CombineFn, no need to GroupByKey first.